# Easiest way to create an irregular time series graph (R? GGPLOT? ITS?)

Tags: r, statistics, ggplot2, time-series

I'm a graphic designer who is trying to use R to create graphs that are too complicated for Excel. I'm specifically trying to create an irregular time series step chart. I've had no problems creating a regular time series chart, but for some reason, the irregular dates are throwing everything off.

I'm starting with a basic text file with two columns of data:

```
01-04-1940    4
05-29-1963    35
12-02-2002    24
```

I've loaded the data using

```
d <- read.delim("file.txt", header = TRUE)
```

and I've converted the first column in Unix time using

```
d$date <- as.Date(d$date, format = "%m-%d-%Y")
```

But at this point, I can't find any more information anywhere on how to proceed. I've seen the R package "ITS," But I cannot find any documentation on it beyond technical descriptions of the classes involved.

I'd much appreciate it if someone with some experience in R could point out the few lines of code I need to create this graph. Thanks!

Comment: Welcome to SO, @Alex.  Nice first question, complete with sample data and code.  Perfect.  +1

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`ggplot` deals quite nicely with data in date format.  Here are some suggestions:

```
d <- data.frame(
    date = c("01-04-1940", "05-29-1963", "12-02-2002"),
    value = c(4, 35, 24)
)

d$date <- as.Date(d$date, format = "%m-%d-%Y")

ggplot(d, aes(x=date, y=value)) + geom_step(colour="blue")
```

[image]

```
ggplot(d, aes(x=date, y=value)) + geom_line(colour="red")
```

[image]

Comment: Andrie, Sorry to bother you more. Thanks for the welcome btw. I think I'm close to this. I followed your instructions to the t with the exception that when creating the data.frame(), I made value = delimtable$value and date = delimtable$date. But when I ran the program, I came up with this http://alexsciuto.com/screen.png. The range of my values is 50 - 1,500 and the dates are 1940 to 2011. Could my wide range of values being throwing things off? Thanks again!

Comment: Figured it out! I had commas in my list of numbers. This confused R. Took out the commas and now the graph looks great.

Answer (score 2):

I would use xts/zoo.  They both handle irregular time series easily.

```
z <- zoo(d[,2], d[,1])
plot(z)
plot(z, type="s")
```